# Jquery animate links

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I want to change the colors of two of my navigation links when the page loads. To make them more visible. I have both jquery and jquery.animate-colors loaded. Here is my code but it doesn't do anything. Doesn't work on my site or JS Fiddle.

```
<div class="main_body">
        <div class="nav1"><a href="http://www.google.com">Test1</a></div>
        <div class="nav1"><a href="http://www.google.com">Test2</a></div>
        <div id="color" class="nav1"><a href="http://www.google.com">Test3</a>    </div>
        <div id="color2" class="nav1"><a href="http://www.google.com">Test4</a></div>
    </div>

$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#color").animate({color: '#3F3FFF'})
});
```

JS Fiddle: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Ux9u5/)

Comment: ids should be unique.

Comment: Id`s are meant to be unique, thats the use of Id`s in jquery. if you want the same behavior to be added for multiple elements , then add a class selector.

Comment: plus in jsfiddle you didnt include jquery. I am not sure,but i think even jquery ui library is needed for animate.

Comment: i was wrong about ui,but jquery is needed.

Comment: I changed the last div to id color2, added jquery to js fiddle, still nothing. http://jsfiddle.net/Ux9u5/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include JQueryUI in your project.

Here is an example : http://jsfiddle.net/UQTY2/142/

Also, do not use same ID for more than 1 element.

```
<div class="main_body">
    <div class="nav1"><a href="http://www.google.com">Test1</a>
    </div>
    <div class="nav1"><a href="http://www.google.com">Test2</a>
    </div>
    <div class="nav1"><a href="http://www.google.com">Test3</a>
    </div>
    <div class="nav1"><a href="http://www.google.com">Test4</a>
    </div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a").animate({
        color: 'green'
    }, 2000)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, jquery cannot animate colours. In order to do that, you need a plugin for it.

You can get one that is part of jquery ui (http://jqueryui.com/animate/) or a standalone one (http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/color-animation/).

Comment: I have both jquery and jquery.animate-colors loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using jQuery (which, as mentioned can't animate colors without a plugin), you can use CSS animations to accomplish this. Also, this fiddle uses your HTML code, but you should correct it to remove the use of the same ID on multiple elements. http://jsfiddle.net/Ux9u5/5/

```
#color a {
    animation: colorchange 5s linear 2s infinite alternate;
    -webkit-animation: colorchange 5s linear 2s infinite alternate; /* Safari and Chrome */
}


@keyframes colorchange
{
from {color: red;}
to {color:blue;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes colorchange /* Safari and Chrome */
{
from {color: red;}
to {color:blue;}
}
```